# StepInput currency format

Tags: sapui5

I have a StepInput defined as below. The idea is that the step is one penny, and the range minimum is 0.01. With 0.01 as the initial value, when I click the + button the value displayed in the control goes to 0.0 and the control is locked.

What I exepected is the 0.01 + a step of 0.01 goes to 0.02.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
<StepInput
        id="unitcost"
        value="0.01"
        min="0.01"
        max="999.99"
        step=".01"
        largerStep="0.5"
        width="10em"
        enabled="true"
        editable="true"
/>
```

See it in action by running this snipped.

```js
 sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
   "use strict";
   sap.ui.controller("MyController", {
     onInit: function() {
     
     }
   });
   sap.ui.xmlview({
     viewContent: jQuery("#myView").html()
   }).placeAt("content");

 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>SAPUI5</title>
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex" data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>

<script id="myView" type="ui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View controllerName="MyController" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form">

    <layout:MatrixLayout>
     <layout:rows>
       <layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
         <layout:MatrixLayoutCell backgroundDesign="Fill1" padding="None">

                    <StepInput
                            id="unitcost"
                            value="0.01"
                            min="0.01"
                            max="999.99"
                            step=".01"
                            largerStep="0.5"
                            width="10em"
                            enabled="true"
                            editable="true"
                    />

         </layout:MatrixLayoutCell>
        </layout:MatrixLayoutRow>
      </layout:rows>
    </layout:MatrixLayout>
    
                    

  </mvc:View>
</script>

<body class="sapUiBody">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1228) has been reported on GitHub and has been categorized as bug. It will be fixed in UI5 as well. However the provided workaround is not sufficient for your case as it is recommended to use just one decimal place for the time beeing. I would suggest to override the default behaviour for the time being. You can do this without changing the original as shown in the [example](https://jsbin.com/qiputet/edit?html,output).

The example replaces the following line:

```
vValuePlusStep.toFixed(1)
```

with the following one, which takes the decimals of the value attribute into account.

```
var decimals = vValuePlusStep.toString().split(".");
return vValuePlusStep.toFixed(decimals[1].length);
```

You can place the code in a separate file, put it into a your app directory  and load it in your main component using sap.ui.define. Lets assume your app is under "app" and you name the file override.js you can load it with:

```
sap.ui.define(["app/override"], function() { });
```

It is not required to pass it into the factory function.

Comment: Thanks Mat. I bookmarked the github issues list and will check there in future as part of my research. The example works as I need. I would like to take the override part out and place in an external file so that I can keep it separated from my main code as it will eventually become redundant - assuming a formal bug fix arrives. Could you suggest where I should park it to keep the separation clean?

Comment: Thanks again. Last question - what was that edit about in you answer where you removed mention of OPENUI5 getting the fix?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that the issue will be solved in both versions, even though the issue has been reported on GitHub for OpenUI5.

Comment: Thanks - I have implemented the workaround and it works perfectly. You may want to add the as a suggested fix to the GitHub case?

Comment: One more query on the StepInput. I bind the value to a part of my JSONmodel. I notice that when I convert this to JSON via JSONStringify() the value is a string, e.g. theVal: "1.99" instead of theVal: 1.99. I find this curious given that a StepInput is inherently working with numbers. Is this by design for some reason?

Comment: This is because toFixed function is called, which returns string. I updated my JSBin examplel with model and adjusted logic. Decimals are now being taken from min value as and the return value is converted to float.

Comment: Ah ok - makes sense. I thought I first noticed this before adding your workaround. I added your fix and all is well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I tested sap.m.StepInput and it is not possible to use smaller step than 0.1. Otherwise step is rounded up or down.

```
0.54 will be rounded down to 0.5
0.56 will be rounded up to 0.6
```

Please look in the jsbin [example](http://jsbin.com/cojiyugovo/1/edit?html,js,output).

So 0.01 is rounded down to 0.

EDITED 2:32 240117:

Here is simple jsbin + [counter](http://jsbin.com/zujefigaka/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thanks for the effort Jaro. I'll keep the question open for a little longer in case anyone has a workaround. It seems baffling that the StepInput does not support currency.

Comment: You are welcome VW. Maybe it is possible to use formatter somehow attached on the change event.

Comment: So what, catch the change, compare the new value to the old (cached) value and use that to detect the increment direction (+/i button) and reset the value to the intended increment? Unless the change event gives an indication of button press vs manual entry by user we could have an issue. And we are still left with the issue of actually displaying to 2dp (or 4dp if the currency requires)

Comment: Yes exactly. You can display what you want. change: function(oEvent){ oEvent.getSource().setValue(sNumberWhatever);} But you will have to make your own counter as you mentioned. I tried and you can set 2dp or 4dp. But one has to make his own logic of counting.

Comment: Do you have a JSBin example for that - I am quite new to SAPUI5 and interested to see how these things should be done. I am having trouble getting my own change event to fire.

Comment: Here is simple example of change event http://jsbin.com/qiwiyuxowe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks - good for my learning. I note also it suffers the issue that if I enter an amount manually then omblur the +0.01 effect happens regardless that I did not pre ss the up/down buttons. A tricky issue.

Comment: thanks for your help. Matbtt provided the best answer though, as it included a workaround for the issue which I have implemented and works. Thanks again.

Comment: It was my pleasure.